# Update products from CSV using import behavior Update only not add new

Tags: magento2, import

Can we update products from CSV but skip new products just update products that already exist. Like I have a CSV which has data with SKUs some already exist some are new but I want to update products not to add new ones when I use import behavior add/update

[image]

it updates products but also add new products from new SKUs. Can we make a custom import behavior that just updates only not add new products?

Comment: No.  It will import everything using SKU as the key.  If it exists it will update it if it does not exist it will create it.  You need to remove things you don't want adding from the CSV.  That is why it is called Add/Update

Comment: is there any way we can do this?

Comment: Write or buy an import module - Easier to just edit your CSV file

Comment: @Anthony actually I have more than 2000 csvs with 5000 products each

Comment: So then you either need to write a Magento module, or you could write a simple PHP module outside of magento to do your compiling.  But either way Magento wont do it as standard

Comment: Thanks yeah making a PHP script for it